# Sampling from maximally skewed stable distribution

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, algorithms

I am reading a paper which refers to a maximally skewed stable distribution $F(x;1,-1,\pi/2,0)$ .   Is there an efficient way to sample from this distribution?

If $X$ has distribution $F(x;\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta)$, then when $\alpha=1$ its characteristic function $\phi(\theta) = \mathbb{E}(e^{-i\theta X})$, $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$ is given by

$$\phi(\theta) = e^{\gamma(-|\theta| - i\theta\beta (2/\pi)\log{|\theta|})+i\delta\theta}.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table 1 of http://arxiv.org/abs/0908.3961v2 contains an explicit algorithm for this.

Answer (score 1):

there are the packages [stabledist](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stabledist/stabledist.pdf) and [FMStable](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/FMStable/FMStable.pdf) that will do this for you.

Comment: Thank you.  I am not sure this package exactly covers the $\alpha=1$ case does it? It seems you would end up taking the limit as $\alpha \to 1$ which is a numerically unstable approach.

Comment: FMStable allows you to set $1-\alpha$ explicitly and claims high accuracy.